# Frontend SVN client, closest thing to Tortoise for the mac

Tags: svn, versions

Just wondering what is the best frontend SVN client like Tortoise for the mac.

Andrei

Answer (score 1):

I thought it was [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I would say SCPlugin -  http://scplugin.tigris.org/